# Create a new web service which can be reachable over internet

Tags: web-services, web

I am not a client server application developer, so posting it here for advice.

I have run into a problem where a warehouse team wants to send information to server. however the warehouse is not registered. warehouse team has few services which they want to expose and they will get the machine connected to internet. I being on the other side should consume the services and send data.

If all systems were in a private lan, it could be achieved, however i am not sure whether it could be attained over internet.

What i think the ideal way is as follows. 
- the warehouse should be hosted/registered. say like www.abcwarehouse.com. and then they should expose the services. Only then these services could be consumed by another machine in other location.

I have tried searching for a solution on internet, but could find mixed information where in some users say it is achievable using IP and some say registering for a domain is required.

As i seek more accurate information in this scenario, request you not to down vote it and reduce the number of views. 
i appreciate your prompt responses.

Comment: Sad to see no responses posted from the whole community of Stackoverflow. :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 
The services could be reachable.

All of the services should be deployed onto a web server. Once deployed, services could be reached from other machines over internet.